# print to file only when a value on one line is immedately followed by another value bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file (xyz.dat) that contains all kinds of random statements.  What I need to do is to search this file for `VALUE1` on a line and only print to file when `VALUE1` is immediately followed on a new line by `VALUE2`.

Example input:

```
1 VALUE1
2 VALUE1
3 VALUE1
4 VALUE2
5 VALUE1
6 VALUE2
7 VALUE2
```

Expected output:

```
3 VALUE1
4 VALUE2
5 VALUE1
6 VALUE2
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`sed`** approach:

```
sed -n '/ VALUE1$/{ N; / VALUE2$/p }' xyz.dat > new.txt
```

---

`new.txt` contents:

```
3 VALUE1
4 VALUE2
5 VALUE1
6 VALUE2
```

Comment: If there is another VALUE1 between 3 and 4, you don't catch it

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed '/ VALUE1$/!d;N;/ VALUE2$/b;D' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk '/VALUE1/{ bkup=$0 } /VALUE2/ && bkup{print bkup ORS $0; bkup=""}' infile
```

Comment: Won't this print `VALUE2` lines even if not preceeded with `VALUE1`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti No, there is `bkup` flag controlling that.

Answer (score 0):

Two **`Awk`** solutions:

-- based on `getline` function:

```
awk '/ VALUE1$/ && (getline nl) > 0 && nl ~ /VALUE2$/{ print $0 ORS nl }' xyz.dat
```

---

-- based on record number comparison:

```
awk '/ VALUE1$/{ rec = $0; rn = NR+1 }NR == rn && /VALUE2$/{ print rec ORS $0 }' xyz.dat
```

---

The output (for both):

```
3 VALUE1
4 VALUE2
5 VALUE1
6 VALUE2
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much.  This did not work on my 35MB data fie (xyz.dat).  However, I created a dummy file (dummy.dat) which looks like this:

Comment: <PLEASE IGNORE PREVOUS COMMENT> Hey Roman... wow thanks so much.  I think I am running into some thing strange!  This did not work on my 35MB data fie (xyz.dat).  However, I created a 100 line dummy file (dummy.dat) including random lines of "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "GARBAGE" and it works FLAWLESSLY!   GARBAGE is omitted and only VALUE1 succeeded by VALUE2 are printed perfectly staggered!  I am confused here but thinking it might have something to do with the size of the file... Any ideas here?  THANKS ALL!